# constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor error alternative

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor, overloading

I have started learning Java and was trying to write some code. I want to throw an error when box(negative) is called, before calling this constructor, but it shows me this error.

> constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor error
> solution

I am aware that the constructor has to be the first thing, but can't I not throw an error before it, or do I have to write code again and again, instead of directly using this()?

This is my class

```java
package oops;

import java.io.*;

class Box { 
    double weight;
    double height;
    double depth;
    
    void vol () {
        double vol = this.depth * this.height * this.weight;
        System.out.print(" volume is :" + vol);
    }
    
    /**
     * triggers Box(double depth) method with depth as 30
     */
    Box(){
        this(30);
    }
    /**
     * triggers Box(double depth, double height) method with height as 40
     * @param depth the desired depth of box
     */
    Box(double depth){
        this(depth, 40);
    }
    /**
     * triggers Box(double depth, double height, double weight) method with weight as 50
     * @param depth the desired depth of box
     * @param height the desired height of box
     */
    Box(double depth, double height){
        this(depth, height, 50);
    }
    /**
     * populates the 3 parameters in the class, given its depth, height and weight
     * @param depth the desired depth of box
     * @param height the desired height of box
     * @param weight the desired weight of box
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if any parameter is negative
     */
    
    Box(double depth, double height, double weight){
        if(depth<=0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative depth size: " + depth);
        if(height<=0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative height size: " + height);
        if(weight<=0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative weight size: " + weight);
        this.depth = depth;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

I have modified the code to throw error in the Box(double depth, double height, double weight) method, but I am unable to throw error before any previous constructor reaches this method, like Box(-4) or Box(1, -5).

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: You cannot do that as constructor call needs to be first statement. That is how they work.

Comment: "*...to reduce unnecessary computing time...*" -- premature optimization is the root of all evil. Why would you think that the constructor call contributes much to computing time?

Comment: BTW: what you want will be previewed in Java 22 as [JEP 447: Statements before super(...) (Preview)](https://openjdk.org/jeps/447)

Answer (score 2):

If you want that, you should make all your constructors `private` (so nobody but you can call them) and then create a `public static` method that allows you to build the object, which performs the checks before calling the constructors. Basically:

```
private Box() {
    //standard code
}

private Box(double depth) {
    //standard code
}

public static Box create(/*parameters*/) {
    //check parameters first
    //if all good call constructor, else throw
}
```

However, just to make it clear to you, you're not going to save any computing time by throwing before or inside the constructor.
It's rather a matter of code style than optimization.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, you can use validation method returning the input, if the validation passes:

```
private static double validate(double value) {
  if (value <= 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("message");
  }
  return value;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Box(double depth) {
  this(validate(depth), 40);
}
```

Inspired by [`Objects.requireNonNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-).

Just to be explicit, I doubt the gains would be substantial enough to make it worth it, unless you want to adopt such code style for the project. TBH [Mateo's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77438009/17795888) with static factory method is cleaner.